# How to highlight/add tag to char in given position of a String

Tags: php, html

I have a string :

```
$str="55798-45366-11255-48084-35644-28027-85391-45536-85002-55350-4166-5991-0313-3681-9382-9143-2852-8142-8643-0235-875-383-839-92-91-00-81";
```

and I want to add tag ( like : `<font color=red> </font>` ) before and after the characters at any position x and y in above string but not contain "`-`" split char like:

```
$str2="55798453661125548084356442802785391455368500255350416659910313368193829143285281428643023587538383992910081";
```

add tag at position x=5 & y=8:

```
55798<font color=red>4</font>53<font color=red>6</font>61125548084356442802785391455368500255350416659910313368193829143285281428643023587538383992910081

$str="55798-<font color=red>4</font>53<font color=red>6</font>6-11255-48084-35644-28027-85391-45536-85002-55350-4166-5991-0313-3681-9382-9143-2852-8142-8643-0235-875-383-839-92-91-00-81";
```

then convert str to array by `explode("-", $str);` or anny way to array.

I tried a lot with `substr_replace($str2,"<font color=red>$str2[$x]</font>",$x,1);` but failed. i dont know how, plz, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be fast, but it's pretty straight forward:

[**Live demo**](http://3v4l.org/CI0BS)

```
function tag($str,$pos1,$pos2)
{
    $offset=-1;
    $arrs=explode("-",$str);
    list($pos1,$pos2)=array(min($pos1,$pos2),max($pos1,$pos2));
    foreach($arrs as &$chunk)
    {
        $len=strlen($chunk);
        if($offset+1>$pos2) break;
        if($offset+1<=$pos2 && $offset+$len>=$pos2)
        {
            $chunk=substr($chunk,0,$pos2-$offset-1)."<span style='color:red'>".substr($chunk,$pos2-$offset-1,1)."</span>".substr($chunk,$pos2-$offset);
        }
        if($offset+1<=$pos1 && $offset+$len>=$pos1)
        {
            $chunk=substr($chunk,0,$pos1-$offset-1)."<span style='color:red'>".substr($chunk,$pos1-$offset-1,1)."</span>".substr($chunk,$pos1-$offset);
        }
        $offset+=$len;
    }
    return $arrs;
}
```

The thought is to explode the string first, and use offset remembering to "simulate" a `substr` search.

You may want to reverse-iterate the process because the code has to check higher position first (otherwise the position for the second `substr` would be incorrect).

You can also further "fancy" the process by using `array_walk` and anonymous function.

Comment: exactly what i need! awesome. thanks you. i dont have enought 15 reputation to vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

Adding tag to a certain position is simple:

`$str = substr($str, 0, $x) . sprintf('<tag>%s</tag>', $str[$x]) . substr($str, $x+1);`

Comment: i mean add tag in origin string contain "**-**", but by the position of number in string with out "**-**"